# Using getline to read into a string but there is newline appearing in each line

Tags: c++, getline

My text file looks something like this:

```
Florida FL
Nevada      NV
New York     NY
```

Now when I read in the file with getline and print it out to the console, there is a newline at the end of every line (besides the last line). Getline is supposed to get rid of newline though. Where is it coming from then?

```
ifstream inFileAbb("abbreviation.txt", ios::in);
while(getline(inFileAbb, line)){   
cout << line;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you're seeing a NewlIne? Not all systems agree on what a line ending should be. For example, if you have a file produced for the Windows OS (NewlIne is Carriage return and Line feed) and consume the file under Linux (NewlIne is Line feed) you often get the Carriage return hanging around and causing trouble. Try printing out the last character in the string as an integer  (`cout  << (int)line.back()`) to see what the actual character value is.

Comment: It's printing 13. So you're right! Coding on Windows would not cause this problem then?

Comment: Using files created according to the native OS conventions prevents this. If you simply copy files from a system with one OS to a system with a different OS you risk exactly this: the line endings are different. There are tools for converting line endings in the file itself.

Comment: Yes, if you have a Windows text file, a c++ compiler targeting Windows would do the conversion for you (and if you DON'T want it converted for you, open the file with the `binary` mode flag.) You don't need to code in Windows though. There should be a [`dos2unix` application](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) that will convert the line-endings of the file for you either installed on your computer or available through your distribution's package manager.

Comment: On windows `notepad++` can fix this `Edit->EOL Conversion->OSType` where OSType is Windows, MacOS or Unix.

Answer (score 0):

The systematic way is to analyze all possible input data and then search for a pattern in the text. In your case, we analyze the problem and find out that

- at the end of the string we have some consecutive uppercase letters
- before that we have the state's name
- we do not care about Carriage Return or New Line  CR of LF or combination of that

So, if we search for the state abbreviation pattern and split that of, then the full name of the state will be available. But maybe with trailing and leading spaces. This we will remove and then the result is there.

For searching we will use a `std::regex`. The pattern is: 1 or more uppercase letters followed by 0 or more white spaces, followed by the end of the line. The regular expressions for that is: `"([A-Z]+)\\s*$"`

We do not care about newlines or whatever. We search for the Text that we want.

When this is available, the prefix of the result contains the full statename. We will remove leading and trailing spaces and that's it.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

std::istringstream textFile(R"(   Florida FL
  Nevada      NV
New York     NY)");

std::regex regexStateAbbreviation("([A-Z]+)\\s*$");

int main()
{
    // Split of some parts
    std::smatch stateAbbreviationMatch{};
    std::string line{};

    while (std::getline(textFile, line)) {
        if (std::regex_search(line, stateAbbreviationMatch, regexStateAbbreviation))
        {
            // Get the state
            std::string state(stateAbbreviationMatch.prefix());
            // Remove leading and trailing spaces
            state = std::regex_replace(state, std::regex("^ +| +$|( ) +"), "$1");

            // Get the state abbreviation
            std::string stateabbreviation(stateAbbreviationMatch[0]);

            // Print Result
            std::cout << stateabbreviation << ' ' << state << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```